# update table in batches using store procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

want to update a table based on the values from other table but my table size is very huge and to optimize query i want to update table in small chunks but i am unable to do so. here is my script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp;
Delimiter //
create procedure sp()
begin
  DECLARE i INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;

  SET @i =1;
  while i < 10 do
    update  
      test t,
      (SELECT yearweek(c.currency_date) w,
              c.currency _currency, AVG(c.rate) rate
       FROM currency c
       GROUP BY w,_currency) src 

    set 
       t.value = t.value/src.rate,
       t.currencyid = 'EUR'
    where 
          w =(yearweek(t.created - interval 1 week) )  
      and t.currencyid = _currency
    limit 20000;

    set i = i+1;
  end while;        
END //
```

when i call store procedure i get error:

> incorrect usage of update and limit.

how can i avoid this and update complete table with batches of `20000` records

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` can be used with `UPDATE` but with the `row count` only

I changed your procedure. Here you can use batch wise update. Every time the value of `i` increases, it will update the multiple of `i` with  `20000` records

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp;
Delimiter //
create procedure sp()
begin
DECLARE i INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
SET @i =1;
while i < 10 do
update  test t,
(SELECT yearweek(c.currency_date) w,
c.currency _currency, AVG(c.rate) rate
FROM currency c
GROUP BY w,_currency) src 

set 
t.value = t.value/src.rate,
t.currencyid = 'EUR'
where w =(yearweek(t.created - interval 1 week) )  
and t.currencyid = _currency and t.id in (select id from test order by id limit i*20000, 20000);
set i = i+1;
end while;      
END //
```

Comment: thanks for answer but  test is my fact table from star schema therefore i dont have primary key

Comment: @Developer please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html. It clearly specifies that ** For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used**.